# footer css issue when deploy in IIS 6.1

Tags: html, .net, css, footer

I set my footer as fixed so that even if the page is scrolled down its footer will remain as is.

When I browse it in VS 2010 run/debug in Chrome, it works perfectly!

But when I deploy it to IIS 6.1, and browse it using Google Chrome it is not doing what I want. It does work, however, in IE and Firefox. Is this a Chrome-specific problem? I am doing something like this:

```
<div id="footer">
   Footer goes here
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#footer {
    background: #2d89ef;
    bottom: 0px;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Open Sans', Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 50;
    left: 0%;
    position: fixed!important;
    position: fixed!important;
    right: 0%;
    text-align: center;
    top: expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+
    (document.documentElement.clientHeight?
    document.documentElement.clientHeight:
    document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe=document.documentElement.scrollTop?
    document.documentElement.scrollTop:document.
    body.scrollTop))+'px');
    visibility: visible;
    width=100%;
}
```

Please advice on possible solutions, thanks!

Comment: Did you check the output in a _real_ browser?

Comment: yes, it's different than what I saw in VS run.

Comment: What browser are you viewing the deployed site in? Are you referring to the Design view in VS2010 or when you run the website through the IDE?

Comment: please see my edit, I run the site using visual studio using Chrome browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to ([restart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms957500%28v=cs.70%29.aspx) your IIS Manager then [clear](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser%27s-Cache) your browser cache. This might solve your problem.

Comment: wow! Sorry for being a noob! Clearing the browser history do the trick! thanks a lot!